# PHP dropdown populated by database to be use javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this php code that get items from the database and i have to use this drop-down in my JavaScript code to duplicate the same drop-down when a button is clicked

```
function dup(){  
     }

 <?php 
  include('view/connect.php');

  $sql="SELECT ss_code FROM ss WHERE sn_id = 1";

  $result =mysql_query($sql);
  $dropdown = "<select name='users'>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $b = $row['ss_code'];
     $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$b}'>{$b}</option>";

  }

  $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

  echo $dropdown;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your items in an array and then set a JavaScript variable to the value returned by encoding it as JSON.

```
var iarray = <?php echo json_encode($items); ?>;
```

Then iterate over the resultant array and create the pulldown from that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean same drop down?If you want same dropdown without any change on a button click you can use jQuery `.clone()`.